# Writing a goose go migration with gorm

Tags: go, database-migration, go-gorm

A default [goose](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose) go migration prepares a function providing an `*sql.Tx`:

> A transaction is provided, rather than the DB instance directly, since goose also needs to record the schema version within the same transaction. Each migration should run as a single transaction to ensure DB integrity, so it's good practice anyway.

I would like to write my migration using [gorm migrations](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#migration), but I’m not sure how to use the given transaction to that purpose. Here’s an example:

```
func Up_20151230135812(txn *sql.Tx) {
  txn.CreateTable(&User{})
}
```

The build gives me `txn.CreateTable undefined (type *sql.Tx has no field or method CreateTable)` as expected. How can I grab the transaction for use with gorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goose know nothing about gorm and his functions (CreateTable etc.)

Look at the end of [goose / lib / goose / migration_go.go](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/src/8488cc47d90c8a502b1c41a462a6d9cc8ee0a895/lib/goose/migration_go.go?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#cl-125)

goose just create transaction

```
db, err := goose.OpenDBFromDBConf(&conf)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to open DB:", err)
}
defer db.Close()

txn, err := db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("db.Begin:", err)
}

{{ .Func }}(txn)

err = goose.FinalizeMigration(&conf, txn, {{ .Direction }}, {{ .Version }})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Commit() failed:", err)
}
```

and use [sql.Tx](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx) from "database/sql" package

but you can implement custom wrapper using gorm ;-)

Comment: I was hoping there would be an existing wrapper somehow like [.Open since this pull request](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/pull/295/files), but for `sql.Tx`.